# Angular Material mat-table is not reloading data on datasource update

Tags: angular, angular-material, httprequest, mat-table

I'm trying to update a mat-table datasource for data reloading. In this case I have this component:

```
import {
  AfterViewInit,
  Component,
  Input,
  OnInit,
  ViewChild,
} from '@angular/core';
import { MatPaginator } from '@angular/material/paginator';
import { MatSort } from '@angular/material/sort';
import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material/table';
import { first } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { EmployeeService } from '../_services/employee.service';

export interface Elem {
  test: string;
  test1: string;
  test2: string;
  test3: string;
  test4: string;
  test5: string;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-employee-table',
  templateUrl: './employee-table.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./employee-table.component.css'],
})
export class EmployeeTableComponent implements OnInit {
  displayedColumns: string[] = [
    'fullName',
    'role',
    'manager',
    'counselor',
    'action',
  ];
  dataSource: any;
  loading = false;

  @Input() areDataUpdated!: boolean;

  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort | undefined;
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator | undefined;
  constructor(private employeeService: EmployeeService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.onEmployeesLoading();
  }

  ngOnChanges(): void {
    if (this.areDataUpdated) {
      this.onEmployeesLoading();
    }
  }

  onEmployeesLoading() {
    this.loading = true;
    this.dataSource = null;

    this.employeeService
      .getAll()
      .pipe(first())
      .subscribe((employees) => {
        console.log(employees);
        this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(employees);
        this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
        this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
        this.loading = false;
        this.areDataUpdated = false;
      });
  }

  onEmployeeDelete(id: number) {
    this.loading = true;
    this.dataSource = null;

    this.employeeService
      .deleteById(id)
      .pipe(first())
      .subscribe((employee) => {
        console.log(employee);
        this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(employee);
        this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
        this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
        this.loading = false;
      });
  }
}
```

When I delete an item, I call the onEmployeeDelete, the dataSource is emptied, and through the employeeService I go for delete and reload new data. It works well.
Instead, when I try to add a new employee, the areDataUpdated input is switched to true, and the ngOnChanges method is launched. areDataUpdated is true, so the onEmployeesLoading is called and data are retrieved through HTTP from backend. But in this case, table is not emptied and data are not updated.

So, in this method

```
onEmployeesLoading() {
    this.loading = true;
    this.dataSource = null;

    this.employeeService
      .getAll()
      .pipe(first())
      .subscribe((employees) => {
        console.log(employees);
        this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(employees);
        this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
        this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
        this.loading = false;
        this.areDataUpdated = false;
      });
  }
```

These rows are ignored

```
this.loading = true;
this.dataSource = null;
```

despite this are ignored, the console.log in the subscribe method shows up data, with new employee added correctly

I don't understand what's the difference with the onEmployeeDelete method, except of the fact that the onEmployeesLoading is called in a lifecycle hook

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the `datesource` like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-employee-table',
  templateUrl: './employee-table.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./employee-table.component.css'],
})
export class EmployeeTableComponent implements OnInit {
  displayedColumns: string[] = [
    'fullName',
    'role',
    'manager',
    'counselor',
    'action',
  ];
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(any);
  
  ...
  ...
```

When then getting the the employees from the get request you can set the `datasource` like this:

```
onEmployeesLoading() {
    this.loading = true;

    this.employeeService
      .getAll()
      .pipe(first())
      .subscribe((employees) => {
        console.log(employees);
        this.dataSource.data = emplyoees;
        this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
        this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
        this.loading = false;
        this.areDataUpdated = false;
      });
  }
```

This way you do not have to set a new datasource every time you make a get request.